# Sends Keys in Selenium and getting rid of the Switch

Tags: c#, selenium, reflection

I am sending Keys in the following manner:

```
    switch (keyName)
    {
         case "Return":
            new Actions(WebDriver).SendKeys(Keys.Return).Perform();                  
            break;
         case "F4":
            new Actions(WebDriver).SendKeys(Keys.F4).Perform();
            break;
         defult:
            "TBD"
     }
```

I would like to get rid of the Switch/Case statement using something like MethodInfo or FieldInfo, But I can't seem to find the right way to do it.

Hopefully you can help...

Thanks

Comment: What about storing the key and the related action in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple function receiving the web element and the text to send to it like following:

```cs
public void sendKeysToElement(IWebElement element, string text)
    {
        elementSendKeys(text);
    }
```

Comment: I need to send Keys.Return or Keys.F1. I can't simply send "Keys.Return"
Also, for some reason Chrome and the site doesn't respond well to what you wrote so I have to use Actions. That's ok but I would like to save the Cases for each F...

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that in the question... But you still can send `Keys.Return` or `Keys.F1` as a parameter.

Comment: I didn't mention it because it's immaterial to my question. I was questioning how to send Keys.Return or Keys.F1 as a Parameter instead of making a case for each one of them

Comment: Okay, have you tried sending it as a string as a parameter as I suggested here?

Comment: yup. sending as text doesn't help